# Set Silverlight grid columnwidth with "*" in codebehind?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Given a simple Silverlight Grid like this:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="MyColumn" Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

I would like to be able to change the Width of the MyColumn column to something like 3* (retaining the *) from the codebehind using C#. Does anyone know how? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
MyColumn.Width = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star);
```

Comment: Geez! How'd I miss that? Thanks Ben M.